# jQuery imagesloaded plugin

Tags: jquery

jQuery imagesloaded plugin

Hi ALL

I'm trying to create a simple slideshow gallery with thumbnails.

I'm using the cycle plugin to create the slideshow and the thumbnails

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/gallerytest/

The thumbnails are in a sticky footer that will stay at the bottom of the window.

I want the slideshow image to fill the rest of the window and scale when the window is resized.

I'm doing this with this function

```
    function resizeImg() {
      $('#slideshow img').css({'height':$('#wrap').height()-footerHeight,'width':'auto'});
    }
```

At the moment this works when the window is resized but not when the image first loads.

I need to call the function when the image is loaded.

I found the imagesloaded plugin which looks like it will work - https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

My problem is I can't see how to use the plugin in my code.

Could anyone explain how I might use the imagesloaded plugin to call my resizeImg function.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <title>Title of the document</title>
      <!--jQuery-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle.js"></script>
      <!--CSS-->

      <style type="text/css">
        *{
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
        }
        ul{
          list-style:none;
        }
        /**/
        html, body {
            height:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #wrap {
            margin:auto;
            min-height:100%;
            margin-top:-100px;
            text-align:left;
        }
        * html #wrap {
            height:100%
        }
        #header {
            background:red;
            border-top:100px solid #fff; 
        }
        #footer {
            background:#eee;
            margin:auto;
            height:100px;
            clear:both;
        }
        /**/
        #slideshow img{
          margin:0 0 0 55px;
          height:100%;
        }

        div#thumbWrap {
          position: relative;
          height: 100px;
          width: 500px;
          overflow: auto;
          margin:0 0 0 50px;
        }
        ul#thumbs {
          display: block;
          width: 2000px;
          padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
        }
        ul#thumbs li {
          display: block;
          float: left;
          padding: 0 4px;
        }
        ul#thumbs a {
          display: block;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul#thumbs img {
          border: 3px #fff solid;
        }
        ul#thumbs a:hover img {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
        #slideshow img { display: none }
        #slideshow img.first { display: block }
      </style>

      </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">

        </div><!-- #header -->
        <div id="slideshow">
          <img src="images/plane01.jpg" alt="" class="first"/>
          <img src="images/plane02.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane03.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane04.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane05.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane06.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane07.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane08.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane09.jpg" alt="" />
          <img src="images/plane10.jpg" alt="" />
        </div><!-- #content -->
      </div><!-- #wrap -->

      <div id="footer">
          <div id="thumbWrap">
            <ul id="thumbs">

            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function() { 

          resizeImg();
          /*-cycle
          */
          $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
              fx:     'fade', 
              speed:  'fast', 
              timeout: 0, 
              pager:  '#thumbs', 
              before: resizeImg(),

              pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                  return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="auto" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
              } 
          });
          /*-thumbnailScroll
          */
          var div = $('div#thumbWrap'), ul = $('ul#thumbs'), ulPadding = 15;
          var divWidth = div.width();
          div.css('overflow','hidden');
          var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');
          div.mousemove(function(e){   
            var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;        
            var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;         
            div.scrollLeft(left);         
          });

          var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();

          function resizeImg() {
            $('#slideshow img').css({'height':$('#wrap').height()-footerHeight,'width':'auto'});
          }

          $(window)
            .scroll(resizeImg)
            .resize(resizeImg)
            .onload(resizeImg)
        });

      </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

-------- UPDATE ---------

I nearly have it working now.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/gallerytest/

The imagesLoaded plugin resizes the first image when it loads and then I use

```
after: resizeImg
```

in the cycle function to call the resize function after the image has loaded.

The problem I'm left with is the jump in image size when the resizeImg function is called after the image has loaded.

Can anyone see a way around this jump in size

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (Add this code inside $(window).load(...) event handler ) -->

```
$('#slideshow').imagesLoaded( function( $images, $proper, $broken ) {
  // callback provides three arguments:
  // $images: the jQuery object with all images
  // $proper: the jQuery object with properly loaded images
  // $broken: the jQuery object with broken images
  // `this` is a jQuery object of container
  console.log( $images.length + ' images total have been loaded in ' + this );
  console.log( $proper.length + ' properly loaded images' );
  console.log( $broken.length + ' broken images' );
resizeImg(); //<<-- At this point in time, all images are loaded in slideshow container
});
```

In addition handle [`after`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) callback of cycle plugin and call resizeImg();

Comment: rt2800 - that works when the page loads and the first image is resized but when the slideshow begins or I click on a thumbnail the image go back to there normal size.

Comment: Ok so I think the imagesLoaded function is called when the images have loaded (When the page finishes loading) - When I click a thumbnail the images have already loaded so the imagesLoaded function won't go - How can I call my resizeImg function when I click a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

In resizeImg, first try using window instead of "#wrap" to obtain the max height to scale your images to:

```
function resizeImg() {
    $('#slideshow img').css({'height':$(window).height()-footerHeight,'width':'auto'});
}
```

To use the imagesLoaded plugin, after adding the script to the head after the others, you could try this line after your window scroll, resize, and onload handlers:

```
$('#slideshow img').imagesLoaded(resizeImg);
```

Comment: Thanks chrisM - I'd tried that already but it doesn't work, Should've put that in my post.